# ZVS low noise power supply?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, zvs

I'm currently looking for low noise isolated DC-DC power supply for analog components. There are different variants available, like SN6501 IC or integrated DC-DC convertors. But I wonder, what if I use a ZVS driver (like one used for tesla coils)? Will it have lower output voltage noise due to sinusoidal current waveform? Actually something like that is mentioned in Fairchild design document:

“The Conventional PWM technique processes power by controlling the duty cycle and interrupting the power flow.  All  the  switching  devices  are  hard-switched  with  abrupt changes  of  currents  and voltages, which  results  in  severe switching  losses  and  noises.”

“Meanwhile,  the  resonant technique  process  power  in  a  sinusoidal  form  and  the switching  devices  are  softly  commutated. Therefore,  the switching  losses  and  noises  can  be  dramatically  reduced.”

Such driver doesn't need to be hi power or hi voltage, just +/-15V for several op-amps. It will be fed with fixed voltage and will have post-regulators, so it can probably have no feedback.

So, is there any sence in such idea, and if the answer is yes, what actual schematic should I use?

[image]

Comment: It would be much more instrumental to think about a ripple eater and post filter after the switching converter, than to compare various switching topologies (IMO).

Comment: All those technics will be implemented as well.

Comment: then I guess just pick the DCDC converter that is the simplest one to fit your specs. The switching noise is typically at 100 MHz up into the GHz range. This is a) easily taken care of by filters b) further rejected by the EMIRR of the opamps. At low power the filter components are essentially "free", so keeping the converter simple is the way to go (IMO)

Comment: That said, if you have the components in your BOM already, then the shown circuit is relatively simple already (I assume it's self-oscillating). So if it meets your specs, go for it.

Comment: Please add a citation and link to the document you are quoting, and a source for the image. As for what schematic, we cannot tell you without more information: what noise level do you require? What voltage and current? Efficiency? Any other features, like short-circuit current limiting, voltage regulation, isolation (how much), etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is well documented. It has been called a ZVS Royer and has been called a tuned collector oscillator. It is sometimes called a baxandall oscillator. BJTs have been used in earlier versions. I have used similar stuff getting DC by using a bridge rectifier on the output. For high currents I have used a choke and for low current high voltage I have used a diode pump. So yes it can work for you. Remember that you do not have much control of VDC out because there is no neg feedback loop controlling duty cycle. When Vin has a large prospecting fault current  like say a car battery then you can place a resistor in series with the pos Vin to defend T1, T2 I have done this on simple low power where a resistor is not a problem. I have prebucked for high power and/or high accuracy.

Comment: FYI, the "Royer" moniker is a misnomer; his original paper discussed core saturation-commutated non-resonant converters without the series choke. This circuit is better called a Baxandall oscillator. (This name is often used in the community, so it's no surprise to see it repeated here; likewise, I'm just doing my part to correct that. Cheers!)